# SWT Application crashes when swt text contains caret

Tags: java, text, crash, swt, caret

In my SWT application I use a SWT text for project number input in a shell based structure. The source code lives [here](https://github.com/ryanthara/RyCon/blob/master/rycon-main/src/main/java/de/ryanthara/ja/rycon/gui/widgets/GeneratorWidget.java).

Nothing special I hope:

```
inputNumber = new Text(group, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

    // platform independent key handling for ENTER, TAB, ...
    // TODO change bad listener with a better one
    inputNumber.addListener(SWT.Traverse, event -> {
        if (!inputNumber.getText().trim().equals("")) {
            if ((event.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) == SWT.SHIFT && event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {
                actionBtnOkAndExit();
            } else if (event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {
                actionBtnOk();
            }
        }
    });
```

When the user fills in the caret character (on mac?) '^' and I hit the escape character to close a shell, the JVM crashes with the following error message. The same can be done with the key left to the backspace '´' on it.

```
2017-10-11 22:35:44.704 java[9862:954273] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
2017-10-11 22:35:44.709 java[9862:954273] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor 
in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new 
applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.getShell(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.traversalCode(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.traversalCode(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.translateTraversal(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.keyDown(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at de.ryanthara.ja.rycon.ui.MainApplication.initUI(MainApplication.java:687)
at de.ryanthara.ja.rycon.ui.MainApplication.<init>(MainApplication.java:94)
at de.ryanthara.ja.rycon.ui.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:137)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anybody have an idea what is missing in my code or what is going wrong here?

Minimal code reduced from my sources:

```
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class MinimumText {

    public MinimumText(final Shell parent) {
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);

        Shell innerShell = new Shell(parent, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.MAX | SWT.TITLE | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        innerShell.setSize(600, 400);
        innerShell.setLayout(gridLayout);

        new Text(innerShell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

        innerShell.setLocation(200, 100);

        innerShell.open();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        new MinimumText(shell);

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

The text field looks this way before hitting the escape key.

[image]

The screenshot from the minimal example looks this way. Same behaviour while hitting the escape key.

[image]

Comment: Show us an [mcve]

Comment: My 'minimal' example lives in the source code of RyCON and has at least 493 lines of code. Sorry for being not so fast, but programming is not my first job.

Comment: You can find it here: [github](https://github.com/ryanthara/RyCon/blob/master/rycon-main/src/main/java/de/ryanthara/ja/rycon/gui/widgets/GeneratorWidget.java)

Comment: All code that you want us to look at must be in the question. It is up to you to cut your code down to the minimum that shows the problem

Comment: Added a minimum example.

Comment: You minimum example works fine for me on macOS 10.13 with SWT from Eclipse Oxygen.1a

Comment: And your variant looks like the picture I inserted? With the marked roof sign?

Comment: @ryanthara The code you provided doesn't create anything that looks like the picture you inserted. Are you actually able to reproduce the issue with _only_ the code you provided? The fact that you're getting a `Widget is disposed` exception makes me think there's something else (perhaps a listener) that is trying to access your `innerShell` after it has been disposed (because you hit `Esc`).

Comment: @avojak Please overlook to my not optimal screenshot. I filled in a current one, which is from the minimal example. The reaction is the same. Hitting the escape key forces the crash.